# What is the relevant formula to calculate a first order amount

Tags: functions

I’m looking for a formula, thanks in advance if you can help.

I need to make several order for a total of $t$ items.
I would like to calculate the first order amount, given that each subsequent order needs to be multiplied by $m$.

$x = \text{first order amount} = 2 = ?$

$nb = \text{number of orders} = 6$

$m = \text{multiplier for each new order} = 2$

$t = \text{total bought amount} = 126$

$(x  m^0) + (x  m^1) + (x m^2) + (x  m^3) + (x  m^4) + (x  m^5) + (x  m^{nb}) = 126$

or

$(x \cdot 2^0) + (x \cdot 2^1) + (x \cdot 2^2) + (x \cdot 2^3) + (x \cdot 2^4) + (x \cdot 2^5) + (x \cdot 2^6) = 126$

What is a relevant formula to calculate $x$ if we know $nb$, $m$ and $t$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Geometric Series**

$$\sum_{i=0}^{nb} xm^i \left(= x \cdot \frac{m^{nb+1}-1}{m-1}\right) = t$$
$$\implies x=t \cdot \frac{m-1}{m^{nb+1}-1}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much. That's it 